# How to add data to multiple input fields and save it on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying add some data to each add input field.

Example if the a "info" input field is added a input field.

If:
The red div and no data gets added the data should be null,
The blue div and a "p" gets added to the added info input on form submit.
The blue div and a "V" is added to the added input field.

How do I add this data to the added inputs and add the data to theirs value on submit?

My HTML and jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/z5qeX/2/

I have an example of this with only 1 input field:

```
    $('.redDiv').click(function() {
        $('#webhost_navn').data('myData', null);
    });
    $('.blueDiv').click(function() {
        $('#webhost_navn').data('myData', 'p');
    });
        $('.blackDiv').click(function() {
        $('#webhost_navn').data('myData', 'V');
    });
// And the form submit button with the id of smt
    $('#smt').click(function() {
        var myData = $('#webhost_navn').data('myData'),
            val = $('#webhost_navn').val();
        if (myData) {
            $('#webhost_navn').val(myData + val);
        }
    });
```

How do I create this function for each added input and save all the data on submit?

When one of the red, blue or black is clicked:

```
1. Select the added input field
2. Create a data variable and save p, V or nothing depending on what div that where clicked. 
3 .On submit add all these variable to values of the correct input fields
```

Comment: I would store an object with var mydata = { "webhost_navn": {red:null, blue:"p", black:"V"}, "....": { ... , ... , ...}} and use .each to attach the click to the divs

Comment: Can you give my an example how to create your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to be entirely sure what your asking but I think what you are looking for is jQuery's live function

```
$('.redDiv').live('click', function() {$('#webhost_navn').data('myData', null);});
```

The live function binds listeners to all newly created controls.

Comment: It should be for every input field. The #webhost_navn is specific  input field. If for instance there is added a input field with the id of #webhost_want the data should be saved to the added input field which would have the name webhost[wantinfo]. Therefor I cannot use a function that only can handle one input field. In your example it is the input field with the id of #webhost_navn

Comment: $('#webhost_navn') could be replaced by any number of jquery selectors. See all here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. If all you are doing is looking to have your data passed from these red, blue, and blackdivs, then just use a selector that would encompass them all.

A good option would be adding a class to all the inputs you might potentially want to target and using the class selector: 

$('.yourClassName') which would select pass the data to all

Comment: Should I make this function for each of my Input fields ?! (50)

Comment: No. the $.live() function will automatically add it to any HTML element that matches the selector. 

$('.redDiv').live('click', function() {$('.dynamicInput').data('myData', null);});, for example, will select all controls with class "redDiv", now and forever, and will send their data to any controls with class "dynamicInput" that exist when you actually click.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
mydata = { "webhost_navn": {red:null, blue:"p", black:"V"}, "....": { ... , ... , ...}}


$('.blackDiv,.blueDiv,.redDiv').live("click", function() {
  var field = $("#"+this.id.replace(this.className,""));
  if (field) field.val(mydata[field.prop("name")][this.className.replace("Div","")];
});

.
.
.
  'id'   : element.prop('id') + 'info',

$(this).parent().append(element).append('<div class="redDiv" id="'+element.prop('id')+'redDiv" style="background:red;width:20px;height:20px;"></div><div class="blueDiv" id="'+element.prop('id')+'blueDiv" style="background:blue;width:20px;height:20px;"> </div><div class="blackDiv" id="'+element.prop('id')+'blackDiv"style="background:black;width:20px;height:20px;"> </div>');
})
```